# How to save result OOP?

Tags: php, oop

I have the following class:

```
class Algorithm {

    public function __constructor($arr){
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

    public function handle(){
        return $this->Q($this->arr[0]); // 1, 2, 3 etc
    }


    public function Q(){
       return 2;
    }

    public function R(){
       return 1;
    }
}
```

I create some instances of class in loop:

```
foreach($arr as $key){
    $objects[] = new Algorithm(["1", "2", "3"]);
}
```

So, I need to handle all values passed to `Algorithm` and return state execution. I mean save result from `Q` and `R` methods in class.

So in result I need to get so as:

```
$objects[0]->Q; //1
$objects[1]->Q; //2
$objects[0]->R; //1
$objects[1]->R; //2
```

After I need to pass result objects in another `class B`:

```
$nextHandle = new B($objects);
```

Where get others result of two functions:

```
class B {

  public function go($objects[0]) {
      return 1;
 }

  public function do($objects[0]) {
   return 1;
  }

}
```

In result also return values `do()`and `go()`

So, problem is that I don't know how to operate of instances of object and pass these for calculation in another class. Also how to save intermediate states of calculations, I mean methods in each class?

Also one of main thinking is how to pass object with all states in another instance of class, that inside I can get state of element passed object?

Comment: It's good to show the code that you have, but I think a better step by step explanation is needed, along with desired outcome.

Comment: There is a some sub-question, it will help me explain more in main question. I have some methods in class. And matrix 3x3 with different values. How can I call methods in class following matrix? I mean create objects with different calling methods? Shortly, how to call methods in class by values in matrix? For example matrix A 0 C, I need to call method A, C. Another: 0, B, A means, I need to call methods: B, A

Comment: For my sub-query I think this will help me: http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html